# Moving Columns using for loop

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I have a master spreadsheet with multiple rows and I want to move each column to a different spreadsheet from the 4th sheet to the last sheet.

I am getting a compile error when I try to run this. The master tab has a variable number of columns called Time, Room1, Room2, Room3,...., SO I have created a seperate tab for each room. Now I want to loop through each column on the master worksheet and move each relevant column to it's respective tab. Is there a better way to do this instead of a for loop within a for loop?

```
Sub MoveData2()

Dim S As Integer
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim F As Long
Dim NameTest As String, NameStr As String
Dim LastRow As Long

Sheets("Master").Activate
Range("B4", "B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Copy
Sheets("Room1").Activate
Range("B5").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste

Sheets("Master").Activate

LastCol = Sheets("Master").Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For F = 3 To LastCol
    LastRow = Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, F).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Master").Range(Cells(4, F), Cells(LastRow, F)).Copy

    'This next part checks to see if worksheet exists and creates if it doesn't exist
    NameStr = "Room" & F
    NameTest = Worksheets(NameStr).Name
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Else
        Err.Clear
        Worksheets.Add.Name = NameStr
    End If
    'End of check if it exists and creates it code

    Sheets("Room" & F - 1).Range("B4").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False

Next F

End Sub
```

Comment: what doesnt work? what does your sheet look like now what is it supposed to look like when the code has finished running? we're not mind readers here you need to share all the possible details

Comment: Try commenting the On Error Resume Next  and tell us if some error appears, and the exact message/problem.

Comment: You haven't actually asked a question.

Comment: sorry, i've edited the post

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub MoveData2()

Dim S As Integer
Dim LastCol As LongSub MoveData2()

Dim S As Integer
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim F As Long
Dim NameTest As String, NameStr As String
Dim LastRow As Long

On Error Resume Next

LastCol = Sheets("Master").Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column

For F = 4 To LastCol
    LastRow = Sheets("Master").Cells(Rows.Count, F).End(xlUp).Row
    Sheets("Master").Range(Cells(1, F), Cells(LastRow, F)).Copy

    'This next part checks to see if worksheet exists and creates if it doesn't exist
    NameStr = "Sheet" & F
    NameTest = Worksheets(NameStr).Name
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Else
        Err.Clear
        Worksheets.Add.Name = NameStr
    End If
    'End of check if it exists and creates it code

    Sheets("Sheet" & F).Range("B4").PasteSpecial
Next F

End Sub
```

Comment: I got an invalid or unqualified reference

Comment: What line did it highlight?  I wrote the code in the webpage, so I might have made a small syntax error.

Comment: Yes I had a period in front of `Columns.Count`

Comment: And fixed another error.  This should work.  Tested and edited.

Comment: You can change some words around if you want the naming structure of the Destination Sheets to be different.

Comment: HEy thanks for the help! I changed your code a little bit and it works for all wkshts except for the last one

Comment: The last one what?  It doesn't copy the last column?

Comment: yea Lets say Room25 is the last wksht the last column won't move to that sheet.

Comment: The only thing I could think of trying would be to add a `+ 1` to the `For Loop` so... `For F = 4 to LastCol + 1`